# Calling non-const member function pointer from const member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass;
typedef void(MyClass::*func_ptr)();
class MyClass
{
public:

MyClass()
{
    f = &MyFunc1;
}

void MyFunc1()
{
    // ...
}

void MyFunc2() const
{
    (this->*f)();
}

func_ptr f;

};
```

If I try to compile, it fails because of MyFunc2() which is a const method trying to call the function pointer of type func_ptr which is non-const.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to cast this. I can use a standard C style cast:

```
    typedef void(MyClass::*func_ptr2)() const;
    func_ptr2 f2 = (func_ptr2)f;
    (this->*f2)();
```

But I'd prefer to use a C++ cast (i.e. static_cast, reinterpret_cast, or const_cast). I got this to compile with reinterpret_cast but I can't get it working with const_cast. I thought const_cast was mean't to be used for this case? Also, is there a cleaner way to do this without having to create another typedef?

Comment: How can there be a **clean** way to call a non-`const` function from a `const` one. There probably is a reason why one of the functions is `const` and the other is not. If not so, just modify the `const` qualifiers.

Comment: The comment above (by @FrankPuffer) should be credited as the correct answer to this question IMO. If those functions are indeed different in their "const-ness", then **don't** call the non-const function from within the const function. If they're not different, then just change the (incorrect) declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in this code.

```
 f = &MyFunc1;
```

Is not well-formed C++ because taking an address of a non-static member function requires a fully qualified name:

```
 f = &MyClass::MyFunc1;
```

---

`this` is `MyClass const*` in a const member function. You may need to cast away that `const`:

```
(const_cast<MyClass*>(this)->*f)();
```

A better solution may be to rethink the design to avoid fighting the type system with `const_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution would be `(const_cast<MyClass*>(this)->*f)();`.

This is legal as long as the `MyClass` instance has been created non-const.
Else, this would invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to compile:

```
MyClass()
{
    f = &MyClass::MyFunc1;
}

void MyFunc1()
{
    // ...
}

void MyFunc2() const
{
    MyClass* mc = const_cast<MyClass*>(this);
    (mc->*f)();
}
```

Comment: Just because a program compiles doesn't mean it's valid, or a good idea.

Comment: This is a fair point. I did not mean to say that because it compiles it it good. I was writing this post meanwhile two others were contributing answers. Reading theirs, it seems that the code part is somehow similar.